# Codeigniter: page background won't load upon submit error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a login page that includes a simple `js` file which will load the `<body>` background image. If I just open the this login page, everything works fine. But when login error occurred or register error occurred, the page will not load the background image.
The login page is loaded like this in the welcome controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('index');
}
```

and the same page is loaded in the login/register controller like this:

```
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
        // validation fail

        $data = array(
            'error_message' => 'Please check your inputs.'
        );
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
   }
```

I did notice that when submission error occurred, the url of the re-loaded index page is http://localhost:8080/cashflow/index.php/login/index
while the normal index page url should be http://localhost:8080/cashflow/index.php

So, how could I have the `js` file run so the background image will be loaded.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must review your `js`or `images` file url path.

Are you locate your `js` right place? It like:

```
<script url="<?php echo base_url('path/to/js.js');?>"></script>
```

Please note that the path to the `js` file when you access the link `//localhost:8080/cashflow/index.php/login/index` path is the same as that you visit the link `//localhost:8080/cashflow/index.php`.

Like that, you should check the url path of `images` background that you set in `body` tag, is it like `style="background: url(/path/to/background.jpg) center top norepeat;"`?

Please note that the path must lead to exactly the `image` or `js` you selected.

Hope this help.